# Fire LostFocus event only when IsKeyboardFocusWithin Property has a false value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

> **What I have:**

I have a combobox. Here is its LostFocus using Command in MVVM style:

```
<ComboBox .............>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OrderIdLostFocusCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

And in the ViewModel:

```
//Constructor
public DispatchViewModel(IEventAggregator _eventAggregator)
{
    eventAggregator = _eventAggregator;

    //Some Code

    OrderIdLostFocusCommand = new RelayCommand(Execute_OrderId_LostFocus);
}

public RelayCommand OrderIdLostFocusCommand { get; set; }

private void Execute_OrderId_LostFocus(object obj)
{
    //Some Calculations

    eventAggregator.GetEvent<MoveFocusToDatePickerEvent>().Publish(true);
}
```

In the Code-Behind:

```
//Constructor
public DispatchView(DispatchViewModel _viewModel, IEventAggregator _eventAggregator)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = _viewModel;
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MoveFocusToDatePickerEvent>().Subscribe(MoveFocusToDateOfDispatch);
}

private void MoveFocusToDateOfDispatch(bool obj)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { dpInvoice.Focus(); }, DispatcherPriority.Render);
}
```

> **Problem:**

When Combobox is focused and if I try to open it's DropDown then its lostfocus event fires and so focus moves to DataPicker.

> **What I want:**

Instead I want to fire LostFocus event only when IsKeyboardFocusWithin property of ComboBox is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an interactions `DataTrigger` on `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` being `false`. It's in the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions` namespace.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ii:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox},
                                    Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"
                    Value="false">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction .../>
    </ii:DataTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: But how can I use a Trigger inside DataTrigger??